# É possível criar contas de acesso para o apache?

Tags: apache, autenticação-http

Sou novo nesta área e estou um pouco confuso com o processo de autenticação de usuários em um website servido pelo apache.
O cenário é, tenho um website e este deve ser acessado através de login de usuário. A minha dúvida é se os usuários aqui em questão fazem parte do sistema Windows ou somente do apache? Quando se fala em fazer login no servidor, se refere ao servidor web apache?
Em outras palavras, a conta de usuário quando criada é reconhecida pelo Windows ou é algo somente interno ao apache?

Comment: Use o apache só para ser o servidor http, e implemente a autenticação dos seus usuários na aplicação, o apache tem alguns módulos de autenticação e autorização mas mexi bem pouco, mais infos https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas e as contas de usuário são criadas no sistema operativo, no meu caso, no Windows? Ou posso autenticar usuários utilizando as contas da base de dados?

Comment: É possível usar autenticação no nível HTTP, mas a URL ficaria algo como https://usuario@dominio/pagina, não fica bonito, tem cara de obsoleto, usávamos isso quando um servidor HTTP estava substituindo um servidor FTP.

Comment: Você autentica usando uma lista de usuários na base de dados, ou seja, na camada da aplicação.

Comment: Você pode autenticar eles pelo banco, isso seria interno na sua aplicação e você teria o controle, sobre autenticar os usuários Windows de uma olhada em autenticação com LDAP

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela resposta.